# Run unittest in a Class

Tags: python, class, oop, automated-tests, unit-testing

I have a test suite to perform smoke tests. I have all my script stored in various classes but when I try and run the test suite I can't seem to get it working if it is in a class. The code is below: (a class to call the tests)

```
from alltests import SmokeTests 

class CallTests(SmokeTests): 

    def integration(self): 

        self.suite() 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    run = CallTests() 
    run.integration()
```

And the test suite:

```
class SmokeTests(): 

    def suite(self): #Function stores all the modules to be tested  
        modules_to_test = ('external_sanity', 'internal_sanity') # This is the name of the file
        alltests = unittest.TestSuite() 
        for module in map(__import__, modules_to_test): 
            alltests.addTest(unittest.findTestCases(module)) 
        return alltests 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    unittest.main(defaultTest='suite')
```

So I can see how to call a normal function defined but I'm finding it difficult calling in the suite. In one of the tests the suite is set up like so:

```
class TestInternalSanity(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        setUp script ....

    def tearDown(self):

        script .... 

class BasicInternalSanity(TestInternalSanity):

    def runTest(self):

        test script ....

class InternalSanityTestSuite(unittest.TestSuite): 

    # Tests to be tested by test suite 
    def makeInternalSanityTestSuite(): 
        suite = unittest.TestSuite() 
        suite.addTest(TestInternalSanity("BasicInternalSanity")) 
        suite.addTest(TestInternalSanity("VerifyInternalSanityTestFail")) 
        return suite 

    def suite(): 
        return unittest.makeSuite(TestInternalSanity)
```

If I have `def suite()` inside the `class SmokeTests` the script executes but the tests don't run but if I remove the class the tests run. I run this as a script and call in variables into the tests. I do not want to have to run the tests by os.system('python tests.py'). I was hoping to call the tests through the class I have like any other function. This need's to be called from a class as the script that I'm calling it from is Object Oriented. If anyone can get the code to be run using Call Tests I would appreciate it alot.

This work's:

```
def suite(): #Function stores all the modules to be tested  
    modules_to_test = ('external_sanity', 'internal_sanity') 
    alltests = unittest.TestSuite() 
    for module in map(__import__, modules_to_test): 
        alltests.addTest(unittest.findTestCases(module)) 
    return alltests 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    unittest.main(defaultTest='suite')
```

This does not work:

```
class SmokeTests():

    def suite(self): #Function stores all the modules to be tested  
        modules_to_test = ('external_sanity', 'internal_sanity') 
        alltests = unittest.TestSuite() 
        for module in map(__import__, modules_to_test): 
            alltests.addTest(unittest.findTestCases(module)) 
        return alltests 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    unittest.main(defaultTest='suite')
```

I can't seem to get this to run in the class, can anyone see the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide  a working source code. This is obviously not correctly copy-pasted (notice the wrong indentation). If you remove SmokeTests.suite() it won't run at all.

Comment: Why are you asking this question again?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606515/problems-running-unittest-test-suite-oo

Comment: @S.Lott -- I re-wrote it to make the question clear to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working, sorry for wasting everyones time, the answer was to change the default test name.

```
class SmokeTests(): 

    def suite(self): #Function stores all the modules to be tested   
        modules_to_test = ('external_sanity', 'internal_sanity')  
        alltests = unittest.TestSuite()  
        for module in map(__import__, modules_to_test):  
            alltests.addTest(unittest.findTestCases(module))  
        return alltests  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Smoke = SmokeTests()  
    unittest.main(defaultTest='Smoke.suite')
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are making unittests much more complicated than they actually are.  Perhaps your implementation should look more like this:

```
import unittest

class MyClass(object):

    def add(self, val, other):
        return val + other

    def subtract(self, val, other):
        return val - other


class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_add(self):
        myclass = MyClass()
        self.assert_(myclass.add(1, 2) == 3)

    def test_subtract(self):
        myclass = MyClass()
        self.assert_(myclass.subtract(2, 1) == 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```